# Overriding definitions in package ```geometry``` while avoiding option clashes

Tags: geometry

I am in a habit of defining a standard collection of CTAN packages in an .sty file and call that file in all documents with a `\usepackage{MyUseCTANPackages}` statement in the preamble of a document. On occasion, rather than voiding MyUseCTANPackages.sty, I would like to override a package defined there, in this instance the `geometry` package to define different margins, which however leads to `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry`. Is there a way to override what was said in the package definitions in MyUseCTANPackages.sty for `geometry`, and similarly also for other packages?

MyUseCTANPackages.sty contains, amongst a large collection of other packages,

```
...
\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin=2.0cm, outer=1.5cm, inner=1.5cm,marginparwidth=2.0cm, marginparsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
...
```

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 20 May 2023
% BRIEF DESCRIPTION:
%   overriding package definitions in package geometry.

%=======================
\usepackage{MyUseCTANPackages}
% attempting to override the definition contained in MyUseCTANPackages.sty:
%\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin=2.0cm, outer=0.5cm, inner=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

sdf asgadf gadf g DGRFe rg ERG edg RSG drg G edgRGedtg G gE TG etrgERGetr gERGer g ERGe rgERG erg ERG erg RG g G rg ERG  rg RG reg RG 

\end{document}
```

Comment: not unless you write your MyUseCTANPackages package to only load geometry if not already loaded, then load geometry first when needed, but loading a large collection of packages not used in the document is an anti-pattern

Comment: you could simply use `\geometry{a4paper, vmargin=2.0cm, outer=0.5cm, inner=1.5cm}` to overwrite the settings.

Comment: @david carlisle point taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load geometry this way inside your MyUseCTANPackages

```
\ifdefined\MyGeometryOptions
\expandafter\usepackage\MyGeometryOptions{geometry}
\else
\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin=2.0cm, outer=1.5cm, inner=1.5cm,marginparwidth=2.0cm, marginparsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\fi
```

and then do

```
\def\MyGeometryOptions{[a4paper, vmargin=2.0cm, outer=0.5cm, inner=1.5cm]}
\usepackage{MyUseCTANPackages}
```

if desired.

The rationale here is in case the order of loading with respect to other packages matters (which probably it doesn't much, but with `hyperref` for example in place of `geometry` it would often).

Comment: This works! But David Carlisle's comment "loading a large collection of packages not used in the document is an anti-pattern" makes me think that my idea of ```MyUseCTANPackages``` was not such a good idea after all. It did take a long period of trial and error to get the packages into an order that made the whole thing work.